# GUI Builder xml exception on build

Tags: xml, codenameone

Using the new GUI builder, I have a simple GUI builder container that causes an error on build, despite of the fact that I did not touch the xml manually.  This was built with the latest version of the cn1 netbeans plugin (v3.8). The error I get is:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/yaakov/Development/workspace/medonline/medonline-cn1-new/MedonlineCn1/res/guibuilder/il/co/medonline/forms/components/DoctorListItem.gui; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 76; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x8) was found in the value of attribute "name" and element is "component".]
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshalException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
    at com.codename1.build.client.GenerateGuiSources.generateGuiSource(GenerateGuiSources.java:241)
    at com.codename1.build.client.GenerateGuiSources.generateGuiSource(GenerateGuiSources.java:231)
    at com.codename1.build.client.GenerateGuiSources.execute(GenerateGuiSources.java:202)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor201.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

My `.gui` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<component type="Container" layout="LayeredLayout" layeredLayoutPreferredWidthMM="0.0" layeredLayoutPreferredHeightMM="0.0"  autolayout="true" name="DoctorListItem">
  <component type="Container" layout="BoxLayout" boxLayoutAxis="Y"  name="Container">
    <layoutConstraint insets="0px 0px 0px 0px" referenceComponents="-1 -1 -1 -1" referencePositions="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0" />
    <component type="Container" layout="BorderLayout" borderLayoutAbsoluteCenter="false"  name="Container_2">
      <component type="Container" layout="FlowLayout" flowLayoutFillRows="false" flowLayoutAlign="1" flowLayoutValign="0"  uiid="PaddedContainer" name="Container_3">
        <layoutConstraint value="West" />
        <component type="Button" uiid="MarginlessContainer" name="ExpertPic">
        </component>
      </component>
      <component type="Container" layout="BoxLayout" boxLayoutAxis="Y"  name="Container_4">
        <layoutConstraint value="East" />
        <component type="SpanLabel" name="ExpertArea">
        <custom name="textUiid" type="java.lang.String" value="LargeText"/>
        </component>
        <component type="SpanButton" uiid="TopPaddedContainer" name="ExpertName">
        <custom name="textUiid" type="java.lang.String" value="BoldText"/>
        </component>
        <component type="SpanLabel" name="ExpertSubtitle">
        <custom name="textUiid" type="java.lang.String" value="LargeText"/>
        </component>
      </component>
    </component>
    <component type="Container" layout="FlowLayout" flowLayoutFillRows="false" flowLayoutAlign="1" flowLayoutValign="0"  uiid="DocListLowerHalf" name="Container_1">
      <component type="SpanLabel" name="ExpertShortDesc">
      <custom name="textUiid" type="java.lang.String" value="SmallText"/>
      </component>
    </component>
  </component>
</component>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**Update**
Running the app in the simulator normally produces no error, but the file doesn't seem to be building - the components I added in the GUI builder don't get generated in the java file.  When I try running `Build` or running the app in debug mode, the error appears and the execution is stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the GUI builder that somehow got the `0x8` character (backspace) into the output. You don't see this character in the editor since it's invisible. Open the file in your editor and retype the "name" entry in line 8 then save. It should workaround this specific error. If additional errors like this exist notice the parser writes the specific line and attribute where corrupted data was saved.